ScrollView takes the entire height when content is small
I'm new to Swift UI and I'm having troubles to make a specific UI behave the way I want.
I have a ScrollView that has some content. This content in a VStack can be as small as 1-3 text components to more than 60 components.
I want the scroll view to grow as much as it needs. Once there's no remaining space just keep using the max available height and make use of the scroll.
The problem comes that even though I have 6 items, the ScrollView takes the entire height and pushes the Text below. You can check the red background and the "Just right below the ScrollView" being pushed down.

struct ContentTestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // ScrollView should wrap content height...
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(0..<6) { index in
                        Text("Item \(index)")
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3))
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                            .padding(.bottom, 4)
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // Fill max width
            }
            .background(.red)
            Text("Just right below the ScrollView")
            
            
            Spacer() // There should be a space if the scroll view content is not too big
            
            Text("Bottom")
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // Fill max width
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(8)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentTestView()
    }
}

I've tried to use fixedSize() but this doesn't work as I expect as it pushes the other VStack siblings and doesn't scroll the way I want.
What's the solution here? I want the ScrollView to grow as much as it needs and once the content fills the entire height it should look like the previous image I showed you.
On android I could achieve by using .weight(1f, fill = false) in the ScrollView but here there's no similar approach.

You might want to consider using ViewThatFits to switch between a VStack that doesn't need to be scrolled and one that does

You could also try wrapping the ScrollView with OptimalHeight, which is a custom Layout implementation that uses the ideal height when possible, but without exceeding the container height. This can be found in the answer to How to make ScrollView shrink to fit and take minimum space without hacks

Hey @BenzyNeez will take a look. ViewThatFits already fixes the issue for >= iOS 16. Thank you everyone!!

As Benzy Neez said in the comments, you can use ViewThatFits if you are on iOS 16+.
Write the content you want to display as the first view in ViewThatFits, then write the same thing but wrapped in a ScrollView, as the second view.
Here it is implemented as a ViewModifier.
struct FixedSizeScrollView: ViewModifier {
    let axis: Axis.Set
    
    init(axis: Axis.Set) {
        self.axis = axis
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ViewThatFits(in: axis) {
            content
            ScrollView(axis) {
                content
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func fixedSizeScrollView(_ axis: Axis.Set = .vertical) -> some View {
        modifier(FixedSizeScrollView(axis: axis))
    }
}

Usage:
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    ForEach(0..<6, id: \.self) { index in
        Text("Item \(index)")
            .padding()
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3))
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .padding(.bottom, 4)
    }
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
.fixedSizeScrollView()
.background(.red)

If you want the content to be scrollable, even when it is small enough to fit, you can write a fixedSize scroll view as the first view instead:
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    ViewThatFits(in: axis) {
        ScrollView(axis) {
            content
        }
        .fixedSize(
            horizontal: axis.contains(.horizontal), 
            vertical: axis.contains(.vertical)
        )
        ScrollView(axis) {
            content
        }
    }
}


Thank you everyone, this already achieves the expected behaviour. Pretty detailed explanation!

I'm going to cry, I found a solution on some article and adapted it.
I was in such a pain using Swift UI. I still need to get used to the way they solve problems that should be much more easier lol
Use GeometryReader in your ScrollView content and save that size in a state. Then use stored size height in the ScrollView.
struct ContentTestView: View {
    @State
    private var scrollViewContentSize: CGSize = .zero
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // ScrollView should wrap content height...
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(0..<5) { index in
                        Text("Item \(index)")
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3))
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                            .padding(.bottom, 4)
                    }
                }
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { geo -> Color in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            scrollViewContentSize = geo.size
                        }
                        return Color.clear
                    }
                )
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // Fill max width
            }
            .frame(
                maxHeight: scrollViewContentSize.height
            )
            .background(.red)
            Text("Just right below the ScrollView")
            
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("Bottom")
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // Fill max width
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(8)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentTestView()
    }
}

